# .Net Core Get json result from another controller action and convert the json string into c# object

Tags: json, asp.net-core, razor

I have a Controller Action which returns JsonResult as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetTotal(int AccountId)
    {
        Account account=context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id=AccountId);

        theTotal=account.Sum(s=>.Amount);

        return Json(theTotal);
    }
```

The above action returns the Total to a Ajax function. However, in few instances I want to get the total in another controller action for further calculation before calling the return View in the action.

How Do i Get the json result in another controller action from the above Action?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you want to call another method which contains `JsonResult` from `GetTotal`? How you want to deserialize JSON string into C# object, and what kind of intended object?

Comment: Sorry for that, theTotal is of type Decimal and I want to deserialize the return json into the decimal form. Lets say I have another action in another controller public ActionResult VIew() { decimal Total="Get Total from GetTotal Action of another controller" } sort of.

Comment: Don't do that. It's not efficient. If you would like to reuse the logic, simply create a new service `MyAccountService::GetTotal(int AccountId)`, and then inject this service as you need.

Comment: Thanks @itminus for the comment. How do I do that can you please eloborate on this?

Comment: @TechCPW It's too long to post it as a single comment, so I post it as an answer below. If you have any further questions, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common service to reuse the logic:

```
public class MyAccountService{
    private AppDbContext _context;

    public MyAccountService(AppDbContext context){
        this._context = context;
    }
    public int GetTotal(int AccountId){
        Account account=this._context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id=AccountId);
        return account.Sum(s=>s.Amount);
    }
}
```

register it as a scoped service.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext")))
services.AddScoped<MyAccountService>();
```

And inject this service in your controllers as you need:

```
public class A1Controler :{

   private AccountService _accountService

   public A1Controller(MyAccountService accountService){
       this._accountService=accountService;
   }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetTotal(int AccountId)
    {
        var theTotal=this._accountService.GetTotal(AccountId);

        return Json(theTotal);
    }
}
```

If you have another `A2Controller`, simply do the same injection.

Comment: Thanks @itminus the above answer is very useful. I am wondering if I need to add bunch of services. Do I need to do it for every service the same thing?

Comment: @TechCPW If you have a branch of services, you could group them into different groups. Every group is treated as a single service.  For example, the `MyAccountService` depends on `AppDbContext`, and provides  `GetTotal()`,`GetAccount()`,`ChangeRole()`and other service method, you just need to register the `MyAccountService` once.  Multiple services (groups) will be  treated as a service layer . In a complicated application, our controller  should avoid operating directly on `AppDbContext`, but rather rely on a service layer.